# How to remove container from homepage only

Tags: magento2, page-layouts, custom-theme

I added  div(container)  in every page  except homepage like this

```
<main>
        <div class="myclass">
              all content here
        </div>
    </main>
```

> I tried update layout from admin and `cms_index_index.xml` file by using `remove` tag but doesn't work for me. I only need to remove that container class or div not all child blocks & containers

Let's consider my container in my `empty.xml` (override).

```
<container name="container_name" htmlClass="myclass" htmlTag="div"/>
```

**It's come as I want  but I don't want it on homepage**

How can I remove that container from homepage.

Comment: I hope my answer will resolve your issue.

Comment: @NikunjVadariya any alternative solution for add div using container  in all pages except homepage ?

Comment: first you need to add it for all page and then remove it for the home page as i describe in my updated answer. it is the sort and good way to solve your issue thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove class by this way:

Go to your `admin panel > cms home page`. There is one tab `DESIGN` and in this tab add your `XML` code in `Layout Update XML area`.

```
<referenceContainer name="container_name" htmlClass="">
```

Keep empty so it will remove the class.

Run command:

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: R U sure this will work ??  because Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'htmlClass' doesn't accept blank value..

Comment: Yes, do it and check it

Comment: can `<referenceContainer>`  be used to add htmlClass?

Comment: @lalitmohan if it will not work then you can add the temporary class like `htmlClass="temp"`

Comment: pls check this..  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Comment: this show error  1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'htmlClass': [facet 'pattern'] The value '' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_]*(\s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_]*)*'.
Line: 782

Comment: @lalitmohan I have updated my answer please check. I hope it will work

Comment: Why would i add this container to homepage when i don't need it  or what about container I added in default layout with same name??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using two ways:

using xml file and add code in admin let me describe both solution.

> solution 1: Create XML file

Create `cms_index_index.xml` file

add code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
      <referenceContainer name="container_name" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```

> Solution 2: add same code from admin side

Go to your `admin panel > open cms home page`. There is a one tab **DESIGN** and in this tab add your xml code in **Layout Update XML** area.
[image]

Both are working as per your requirement.(y)

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention what I tried I already tried this  .  I need to remove my that div /class not all container . it remove all containter child containers and blocks also

Comment: @lalitmohan It will be like       
<referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlClass="new-class-name"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare block for magento theme.

Place block declaration into the

> Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml

file.

for magento module

place block declaration into the

> app/code/yourmodule_namespace/your_module/view/frontend/layout

ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
  <referenceContainer name="page.top"> 
        <container name="banner" as="banner" label="Banner"   htmlTag="div" htmlClass="banner" htmlId="banner">
            <block class="Magestore\Bannerslider\Block\Bannerslider" name="bannerslider.content.top" before="-" />
       </container>      
</referenceContainer>
```

You can refer this [blog](https://unitedwebsoft.in/blog/show-block-frontend-home-page-inside-magento-2-version/) for better understanding.

Comment: I already have that `cms_index_index.xml` I know very well. I need to remove only class not child containers & blocks within that container